# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have project zend framework in localhost work but when i upload in the 1&1 i have this Error:
Warning: require_once(/../library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/9/d675656264/htdocs/project/public/index.php on line 18

Here my index.php

```
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'production');
// Define path to application directory
defined ( 'APPLICATION_PATH' ) || define ( 'APPLICATION_PATH', realpath ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/application' ) );

// Define application environment
 defined ( 'APPLICATION_ENV' ) || define ( 'APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv ( 'APPLICATION_ENV' ) ? getenv ( 'APPLICATION_ENV' ) : 'production') );
 // Ensure library/ is on include_path

$rootPath = dirname(__FILE__);
set_include_path(
    PATH_SEPARATOR . $rootPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/../../library' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

// To enable autoloader, (this is a new way of using autoloader)
require_once  '/../library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `__DIR__` so it uses the full path

`require  __DIR__.'/../library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';`

Comment: Thanks always i have the error;Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/9/d675656264/htdocs/project/public/../library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path='/homepages/9/d675656264/htdocs/batsuivi/library/:.:/usr/lib/php5.6') in /homepages/9/d675656264/htdocs/project/public/index.php on line 24